# QDeclarativeImageProvider does not load image in container

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```
Image {
        id: backImage
        source: "image://imageprovider/frontimage"
    }
```

works fine, but doesn’t work with Column or another container

```
Column {

    Image {
            id: backImage
            source: "image://imageprovider/frontimage"
        }
}
```

whereas

```
Column {

    Image {
            id: backImage
            source: "screen1.png"
        }
}
```

OK.
Why?

Declaration:

```
class QMLImageProvider : public QObject, public QDeclarativeImageProvider
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QPixmap front;
    QPixmap back;

public:
    explicit QMLImageProvider();
    QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);
};
```

implementation:

```
QMLImageProvider::QMLImageProvider() : QObject(0),
        QDeclarativeImageProvider(QDeclarativeImageProvider::Pixmap) {}

QPixmap QMLImageProvider::requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) {
    return QPixmap(QString("QML/screen1.png"));
}
```

registration:

```
screenArea = new QDeclarativeView(wgScreenArea);
    qmlImageProvider = new QMLImageProvider();
    screenArea->engine()->addImageProvider(GlobalVars::imageProviderID, qmlImageProvider);

    screenArea->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("QML/screen.qml"));
    screenArea->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
```

P.S. Sorry for my english.

**~SOLVED~**

```
Column {
    id:screenImage
    Image {
        id: backImage
        width: screenImage.width
        height: screenImage.height
        source: "image://imageprovider/backimage"
    }
}
```

It Works!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly that the `Image` using the `ImageProvider` doesn't declare its width and height correctly?  `Column`s get a bit funny with items that don't declare their width and height.  Try hard coding the `width` and `height` in your `Image` in your second example and it should work.